# Spring-data-neo4j multiple graphs

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I know there's some similar topic out there, but none of them gives a solution. So, if using Spring-data-neo4j, is there any way to connect to multiple graphs? NOT graphs in the same instance with different labels.

Or equivalently, I can ask this question:

How can I configure spring-data-neo4j to have multiple sessions to different Neo4j instances on different ports.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Thanks to @Hunger, I think I am one step forward. Now the question is: how to confiture spring-data-neo4j to have multiple 'PereistenceContext' and each of them refers to an individual Neo4j instance.

Comment: Which version do you use?

Comment: I am using Spring-data-neo4j 4.0.0.RELEASE and Neo4j 2.3.2.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure different application contexts with different REST-API's declared pointing to different databases.

You should not mix objects or sessions from those different databases though. 
So you might need qualifiers for injection.

Comment: This sounds like a good ides. Is there any documents? One thing bother me is how to tell the repositories which session to use? For example, in cypher like `@Query("MATCH (n) RETURN n")`.

Answer (score 0):

How about having multiple configurations :

```
//First configuration
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "org.neo4j.example.repository.dev")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class MyConfigurationDev extends Neo4jConfiguration {

 @Bean
 public Neo4jServer neo4jServer() {
    return new RemoteServer("http://localhost:7474");
 }

 @Bean
 public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    // with domain entity base package(s)
    return new SessionFactory("org.neo4j.example.domain.dev");
 }

 // needed for session in view in web-applications
 @Bean
 @Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
 public Session getSession() throws Exception {
    return super.getSession();
 }
}
```

and another one

```
//Second config
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "org.neo4j.example.repository.test")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class MyConfigurationDev extends Neo4jConfiguration {

 @Bean
 public Neo4jServer neo4jServer() {
    return new RemoteServer("http://localhost:7475");
 }

 @Bean
 public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    // with domain entity base package(s)
    return new SessionFactory("org.neo4j.example.domain.test");
 }

 // needed for session in view in web-applications
 @Bean
 @Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
 public Session getSession() throws Exception {
    return super.getSession();
 }
}
```